# Filter dynamic in power bi

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, powerpivot, powerbi, powerview

Is it possible to do a dynamic filter in power Bi?

I want to show TOP 20 or TOP 10 or TOP 5 in columns chart. Now I have a filter with less 20 , but I need to mark in slice and show other data.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, there is no out of the box function to do TOP N. 
When I have to do this, I used the following method to do that

let's imagine the following table (Table1):

I add a column with this DAX formula:
rang = RANKX(Table1,Table1[Sales])

And then, I add another column with TOP N Formula
Top = IF(Table1[rang]<=2,"TOP2")
[Table in Power BI Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrxph.png)

In the report, I add a slicer based on the TOP N column
[Report Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvE8B.png)

The only thing is that the blank value still remains in the slicer.
Another way to do kind of top N, is to still add a column with rank and add this column to report level filter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no native Top N functionality in Power View visualizations. That being said, if you want to do a Top N based on a single field and measure you know in advance, you can write a measure to account for that using the [pattern here.](https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/adding-top-10-charts-to-power-view-which-honor-filters/)

[You can vote for this feature here.](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6515731-top-n-filters)